# Angular 2 file upload in form and Java

Tags: java, file-upload, angular

I have front end in Angular2 and back end in Java. I work with Java and found this task with Angular a bit tricky.

I need to upload a file in a form. How can a file be added to a form object, just like the rest of the field's values. is it possible at all?

I mean like this

```
onSubmit() {
        if (this.isSubmitting)
            return;

        this.isSubmitting = true;

        let newService = {
            name: this.editServiceForm.value.name,
            summary: this.editServiceForm.value.summary
            logo: this.editServiceForm.value.logo <-----------like this
        };
```

when i do that i get empty string for logo. all other "normal" string fileds are correct.

i saw a lot of solutions of file uploading here on StackOverflow they all describe uploading a file in a separate request. like this
    template: 
          `<div>
            <input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)"/>
          </div>`
,

.....

```
onChange(event) {
    console.log('onChange');
    var files = event.srcElement.files;
    console.log(files);
    this.service.makeFileRequest('http://localhost:8182/upload', [], files).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('sent');
    });
  }
```

here in this.service.makeFileRequest we sending a request specially for file upload.

if i do this i need to handle this request separately and then also other data from the form separately (like name and summary). If so what would be the correct way to handle this in java?